# $(2, 1 + \sqrt[]{−17})$ is a prime ideal in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[]{-17}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-factorization

How can we see that $(2, 1 + \sqrt[]{−17})$ is prime ideal in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[]{−17}]$?

We have \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-17}\right]}{\left(2, 1 + \sqrt{-17}\right)} &\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2 + 17)}{(2, 1 + x, x^2 + 17)/(x^2 + 17)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2, 1+x, x^2 + 17)}.
\end{align*}

I don't see why this is an integral domain? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is $(2)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?? Is $(2,1+x)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?? Is it a maximal ideal?? what about $(2,1+x,x^2+17)$??

Comment: Yes $(2)$ is prime ideal in $\Bbb Z[x]$. If $(2,1+x)$ is maximal, then obviously $(2,1+x,x^2+17)$ is maximal but I don't see if $(2,1+x)$ is prime

Comment: Does it then answer your question!?? Any maximal ideal is prime ideal.. so, The quotient that you get is not just an integral domain but a field... Is it clear?

Comment: Yes but what I don't understand is why $(2,1+x)$ is maximal

Comment: what maximal ideals do you know in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$??

Comment: It might sound rude but I think before looking for a more general rings, it is necessary to understand what are all principal, maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}[x]$...

Comment: Thank for the person who downvoted to say why. @PraphullaKoushik All these notions are well understood.

Comment: Does that mean you know what are maximal ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? But you just said you don't understand why $(2,1+x)$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$...

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]}{(2,1+\sqrt{-17})}\simeq\frac{\frac{\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]}{(2)}}{\frac{(2,1+\sqrt{-17})}{(2)}}\simeq\frac{\Bbb Z_2[i]}{(1+i)}\simeq\Bbb Z_2.$$
Here I have used, Third Isomorphism theorem and reduction modulo $2$.

Comment: Thank you! How do we get  $\frac{\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]}{(2)} \cong \Bbb Z_2[i]$?

Comment: Reduction modulo $2$. I mean consider $1\mapsto \overline 1\in \Bbb Z_2[i]$ and $\sqrt{-17}\mapsto i\in \Bbb Z_2[i]$. And then show this is a well defined ring homomorphism with kernel $(2)$.

Comment: @PerelMan Another way to see it: $\frac{\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-17}]}{(2)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2, x^2+17)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+17)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+1)}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_2[i]$ doesn't really make sense. Over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, $x^2 + 1 = (x+1)^2$ is reducible with $1$ as a double root, so there is no such thing as $i$.

Comment: @André3000 You are right. I sholud write, $\frac{\frac{\Bbb Z_2[x]}{(x^2+1)}}{\frac{(1+x)}{(1+x^2)}}$ instead of 
   $\frac{\Bbb Z_2[i]}{(1+i)}$ as $\Bbb Z_2[i]$ is meaningless. Thanks for pointing out my fault.

Answer (score 2):

A general element of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-17}]$ is $a + b\sqrt{-17}$ for $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$.  When you mod out by $(1+\sqrt{-17}) \subset (2,1+\sqrt{-17})$, you impose the relation $\sqrt{-17} = -1$, so 
$$  a + b\sqrt{-17} \cong a-b \pmod{(1+\sqrt{-17})}  \text{.}  $$
This makes $\frac{\Bbb{Z}[-17]}{(1 + \sqrt{-17})}$ (a subring of) $\Bbb{Z}$.  (There's a reasonable chance that $(1 + \sqrt{-17})$ contains an integer, perhaps something near $18$, so we may actually have a much smaller ring than $\Bbb{Z}$.)  Then when we quotient by $(2)$, we get either $\{0\}$ (a.k.a., the one ring) or $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.  The former happens when we actually have $\Bbb{Z}$ mod an odd number (because having both $\text{"some odd integer"} \cong 0$ and $2 \cong 0$ sends all of $\Bbb{Z}$ to zero) and the latter when we actually have $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{Z}$ mod an even number after the first quotient.

If you can show $(2, 1+\sqrt{-17})$ is a proper ideal, you do not get the one ring.  So you get a field, showing that $(2, 1+\sqrt{-17})$ is a maximal ideal.  Since maximal ideals are prime ideals, $(2, 1+\sqrt{-17})$ is a prime ideal of $\Bbb{Z}$.

Can show $(2, 1+\sqrt{-17})$ is a proper ideal?

Comment: Thank you! If $(2, 1+\sqrt{-17})$ is not proper then $\sqrt[]{-17} \in \Bbb  Z$ which is a contradiction. But I still don't get why only $\{0\}$ or $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. if $\frac{\Bbb{Z}[-17]}{(1 + \sqrt{-17})}$ is a subring of $\Bbb Z$, it is of the form $n\Bbb Z, n\in \Bbb N$. If $n$ is even we have $\{0\}$, if $n$ is odd we have  $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. Does that make sense? and how did you get intuition for 18?

Comment: @PerelMan : Your argument for properness is incorrect.  If $n$ is **odd**, $\frac{\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}}{(2)} \cong \{0\}$.  If $n$ is **even**, $\frac{\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}}{(2)} \cong \Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}$.  And for "$18$": what's the norm of $1+\sqrt{-17}$?  (I.e., what do you get when you multiply it by its conjugate?)

Comment: Right for 18 it is cristal clear thank you. For the argument about properness. Denote $a:=\sqrt[]{-17}$. Suppose $1 \in (2,1+a)=2\Bbb Z[a]+(1+a)\Bbb Z[a]$ then $\exists \alpha  ,\beta,\alpha ', \beta ' \in \Bbb Z$ s.t.  $1=  2(\alpha  a+\beta  )+(1+a)(\alpha 'a+\beta ').$ Since $a^2\in \Bbb Z$  you end up with $a\in \Bbb Z$. Is it argument incorrect? Then when you mention (a subring of) $\Bbb Z$, for me it is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$ so I think of $n\Bbb Z$ for some integer $n$, not about $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$. Maybe just a matter of terminology?

Comment: @PerelMan : Your conclusion is bizarre.  From your equation in $a$, $b$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha'$, and $\beta'$, you are forced to solve the system $2\beta + a^2 \alpha' + \beta' = 1$, $2\alpha + \alpha' + \beta' = 0$, obtained by collecting in powers of $a$.  From these, $18\alpha' = -1 -2\alpha+2\beta$ and $18\beta' = 1 - 34 \alpha - 2\beta$ and you have to ask are there integers $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\alpha'$, and $\beta'$ satisfying these equations?  The answer is clearly no because even numbers aren't equal to $1$ or to $-1$.

Comment: Thanks again Eric, I was hasty and yes I see now my argument is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Modding out by $x+1$ is the same as setting $x = -1$. Or more precisely, using the Third Isomorphism Theorem
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(2, 1+x, x^2 + 17)} & \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]/(1+x)}{(2, 1+x, x^2 + 17)/(1+x)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}[-1]}{(2, (-1)^2 + 17)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(2, 18)} = \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(2)} \, .
\end{align*}